# step through a paginated result item by item

Tags: reactjs, react-query

Given a paged API I can display each page and let the user step through the pages. On each page the user sees e.g. 9 items.

Using react-query 4 we could do

```
function Todos() {
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0)

  const fetchProjects = (page = 0) => fetch('/api/projects?page=' + page).then((res) => res.json())

  const {
    isLoading,
    isError,
    error,
    data,
    isFetching,
    isPreviousData,
  } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['projects', page],
    queryFn: () => fetchProjects(page),
    keepPreviousData : true
  })

  return (
    <div>
      {isLoading ? (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      ) : isError ? (
        <div>Error: {error.message}</div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          {data.projects.map(project => (
            <p key={project.id}>{project.name}</p>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
      <span>Current Page: {page + 1}</span>
      <button
        onClick={() => setPage(old => Math.max(old - 1, 0))}
        disabled={page === 0}
      >
        Previous Page
      </button>{' '}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          if (!isPreviousData && data.hasMore) {
            setPage(old => old + 1)
          }
        }}
        // Disable the Next Page button until we know a next page is available
        disabled={isPreviousData || !data?.hasMore}
      >
        Next Page
      </button>
      {isFetching ? <span> Loading...</span> : null}{' '}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I want to implement a details page, s.th. like this:

```
function TodoDetails({ item, isLoading, isError, onPrevious, onNext }) {

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  if (isError) {
    return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{todoItem.name}</h2>
      <p>{todoItem.description}</p>
      <button onClick={onPrevious}>
        Previous
      </button>
      <button onClick={onNext}>
        Next
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I don't understand how to implement the onPrevious and onNext functions. How can I let the user step through the projects and automatically load pages if hitting an item that is on a page that is not yet loaded? E.g the user opens the details for the last item on the current page and clicks `next`. Then the next page needs to be fetched to show the first item on that page.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when you are on a details page, you'd have a separate Query to fetch exactly that single detail. If you want to operate only on the paginated list query, I would probably still create a detail query for each item, but instead of making a request, I'd try to:

- look at all the cached entries with `queryClient.getQueriesData({ queryKey: ['projects'] })`, loop through it and try to find that entry.
- if it exists, you can just return it
- if it doesn't exist, you'd have to fetch the next page with `queryClient.fetchQuery` and then repeat the process.

Something like:

```
useQuery({
  queryKey: ['projects', 'detail', id],
  queryFn: async () => {
    const existingProjects = queryClient.getQueriesData({ queryKey: ['projects'] })
   const entry = findInExistingProjects(existingProjects, id)
   if (entry) return entry
   const nextPageNumber = getNextPageNumber(existingProjets)
   const data = await queryClient.fetchQuery({
     queryKey: ['projects', page],
     queryFn: () => fetchProjects(page),
   })
   
   // now `data` should contain that entry I guess ? But what if not ..
   return findProject(data, id)
  }
})
```

This is mostly pseudo-code, but it's a bit complex. I think the easiest way would be to just request it from the backend again, and maybe populate the entry with initialData to avoid initial fetches if you have data from the list page. It's okay to return `undefined` from `initialData`, it will just mean it has to fetch it from the api in all cases:

```
useQuery({
  queryKey: ['projects', 'detail', id],
  queryFn: () => fetchProject(id),
  initialData: () => {
    const existingProjects = queryClient.getQueriesData({ queryKey: ['projects'] })
    return findInExistingProjects(existingProjects, id)
  }
}
})
```